# Change the description of the closing reasons given in the FAQ

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons

When a question is closed, a text is visible at the bottom of the question, which explains the reason for closing the question, such as:

> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable, [see the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#close).

The link to the FAQ shown under the question should probably all point to /faq#close.

The description of the closing reason given in the FAQ should be expanded, and not have the sentence that takes the users back to the FAQ itself. For the description I quoted, that would mean to change it at least to:

> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

Comment: That was exactly what it was... *before* they added the FAQ link.

Comment: I quite like the idea of someone stuck in an infinite loop constantly trying to find the FAQ... maybe they'll read it eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the new [Help Center](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/helpcenter) has been deployed, this is not anymore the case. [Why are some questions closed, and what does "closed" mean?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/closed-questions) which lists all the possible closing reasons, doesn't have anymore a link to itself in the closure descriptions.

[image: screenshot]