# There are links that take you to the same FAQ section you are in

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, site-faq

I was reading [this part of the FAQs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#close) and lost about 2 hours of my life because this endless looping created by visiting the links (the ones in the *Common reasons* **not constructive** and **too localized**)

I am somewhat slow, and it was not until the 243th time that I realized these links where taking me to the same section over and over again.

Can someone look into that and remove the links (or link to somewhere else)?

**Note:** it seems like this 'issue' exists [in other FAQs](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) too (not just in meta)

Comment: I strongly agree with your use of quotes around the word "issue".

Comment: I have a [similar request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136270/can-the-links-be-disabled-in-the-vote-to-close-dialog) complaining about those links. They really ought to only be hyperlinked when they're in the box on the question. The two other places they show up, they're either useless or annoying... Also, 2 hours? Really?

Comment: Also, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146677/change-the-description-of-the-closing-reasons-given-in-the-faq ... I'm not 100% certain what to do in a 3-way duplicate triangle thingy but I think @animuson was first?

Comment: @Ben I think is not that triangular, the request of animuson is different in many ways, but that link you gave looks like a possible candidate (but I am unsure). I will leave this to see what the community thinks

Comment: I think it's about time we added a [recursion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149528/there-are-links-that-take-you-to-the-same-faq-section-you-are-in#comment429941_149528) section to the Stack Overflow FAQ.

Comment: **day 3:** _I have no food left, I am starting to run low on water, but I am very close to finally understand why I keep being redirected to Shog9's comment_